# Cuts off form data when setting url as value

Tags: javascript, cookies, urldecode, form-data

This script creates a cookie depending on form data, (ex: *?docname=My Document*)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
var docname = getValue("docname"); // these go off another script to get form data
    var save = getValue("save");
    var url = window.location.href;
}
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
function saveDoc() {
    if (docname != '') {
        setCookie(docname,url,730);
    }
    else {
     // Nothing else to do
    }
}
// Helps to find errors if they exist
window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
    var errorText = 'message: ' + errorMessage + '\nurl: ' + url + '\nline: ' + line + ' please contact us, and report this error.';
    alert(errorText);
}
</script>
```

It creates the cookie and sets the name of it as the *docname* variable, but when it sets the url as the value, it cuts off the form data.

I've researched and changed the code but couldn't find an answer, can anyone help?

**Solution**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
{
var docname = getValue("docname"); // these go off another script to get form data
    var save = getValue("save");
    var url = window.location.href;
    var recode = encodeURIComponent(url);

}
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
function saveDoc() {
    if (docname != '') {
        setCookie(docname,recode,730);
    }
    else {
     // Nothing else to do
    }
}
// Helps to find errors if they exist
window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
    var errorText = 'message: ' + errorMessage + '\nurl: ' + url + '\nline: ' + line + ' please contact us, and report this error.';
    alert(errorText);
}
</script>
```

changed the variable used to set the value to `recode` and set recode equal to `encodeURIComponent(url);` so it decodes the `url`, decoding it and making it possible to have form data in a value or name of a cookie, etc. Thanks to @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) is your friend here

```
document.cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + expires + "; path=/";
```

and when you get it, you need to decode it with [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Comment: could I use that like this: `encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)` cause its still creating the cookie with new-doc.html?docname and not new-doc.html?docname=My Document&value=somthing, etc. @epascarello